# Lambda function not working properly

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to write a lambda function to do the same program which I already implemented using a `while` loop, but I am not able to figure out how to correct my current program using the lambda function.  As here, I want to multiply 4 with decreased value of `n`.  For example, 3 should work like `4*3=12` and then `12*2=24`, but here it's multiplying 4 always with 3 if `n=3`. Using a `while` loop, I wrote this program like below given in `foo` function.
It's not factorial; basically, I want to print this series for different values of n like:

```
n=1 ans=4,
n=2 ans=8,
n=3 ans=24,
n=4 ans=96,
n=5 ans= 480.
```

The logic in `foo` function is generating this output.

```
foo= lambda n: 4*n**~-n
```

---

```
def foo(n):
  a=4
  i=1
  while i<=n:
      a*=i
      i+=1
  return a
print(foo(7)) #20160
```

Comment: Why not `from math import factorial; foo = lambda n: 4 * factorial(n)`?  Even better, **define a function**.  Named `lambda`'s are against their purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is a [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) [bitwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) operator meaning `NOT`.   `~x` is equivalent to `-x - 1`.  Let's break this down:

4*n**~-n == 4*3**~-3 == 4*3**(~-3) == 4*3**2 == 4*(3**2) == 4*9 == **36**

What you want is to find `4 * factorial(n)`.  You can import the `math` module to do that:

```
from math import factorial

def foo(n):
    return 4 * factorial(n)
```

This would interpret to:

```
from math import factorial

foo = lambda n: 4*factorial(n)
```

The problem with the above approach is that `lambda`s were created to be *nameless*.  Using a `lambda` when you want to use it more than once is against their intent.  Just stick with the function.

Comment: Thank you, actually my program is not to find factorial. It will generate numbers like as given above in question statement

Comment: Try out my function.  It is indeed factorial.  You will find that all test cases pass.

Comment: for n=5, your function will generate 120 while my function will generate 480. its just i don't know how to do it using lambda

Comment: My function generates `480`.  Try it.

Comment: The simple fact is that `lambda`s cannot do `while` loops.  You need to find a new way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115161/discussion-between-khushboo-tiwari-and-zondo).